# How to define an image which is a link in markdown so it will be parsed by doxygen

Tags: markdown, doxygen, github-flavored-markdown, doxygen-wizard

I have a markdown file which has an image which is also a link with this syntax :

```
[ ![image caption] (http://image-path) ] (https://when-the-image-is-clicked-get-here)
```

I'm using USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE from doxygen to show my MD file as the main documentation page. In github the MD file works as expected but when I try to generate HTML using doxygen I get the following warning :

> warning: Unexpected html tag  found within  context

how should I define the image link so it will be parsed correctly by doxygen?

doxygen version : 1.8.11

Comment: seems like this is an open bug : https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=769223

Comment: Try removing the space between `] (` for each. Some Markdown parsers see that as not being a link/image.

Comment: nope, didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you **remove spaces** it will work, because it worked for me.